# Using Service Worker API in a multi site environment

Tags: javascript, ssl, multisite, service-worker

So with all the new stuff like notifications and offline caching available now with the service worker api I've been looking to add it to my web app.

The only thing is I can't seem to figure out is how to deal with the the https/ssl issue.

My site allows people to host websites in an online no code environment. New sites are accessed by subdomains off the main domain. This by itself I can only see requiring a wildcard subdomain ssl cert.

The complication I'm facing is that premium sites can add their own top level domain. Which will break the service worker as far as I can tell.

All these sites only require the user to sign up once so users are shared between sites and you can also get your notifications and messages cross site.

I would like to take advantage of the notifications part of the api for mobile but I'm going to need to get around this issue first.

Any help or enlightenment on this would be much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

As [Alex Russel pointed in his article](https://infrequently.org/2014/12/psa-service-workers-are-coming/):

> Service Worker scripts must be hosted at the same origin

and Service Worker can't work outside its scope. Subdomains [are not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) the same origin, so you'll need specific worker for specific client's page.

However, I can't see a problem here - when someone will enter `yourpremiumclient.com`, DNS server (ex. cloudflare, which offers free HTTPS and can force HTTPS) will point to your server, where worker could install and control this domain scope. Of course, the same worker won't be able to control your default scope ex. `yourclient.yourdomain.com`.

Comment: I may not have done a good job of fully explaining myself. I'm aware of the same origin policy. All scripts are running from the domain that called them. What I'm having a problem with is having a valid ssl portal for all possible ways someone could interact with the site. Like when a customer users their own domain name. As far as I can tell if my main ssl tries to validate from their domain it will fail and will make customers think they are on a non secure connection.